# One message processed OK, Next message rejected and goes to deadletter

Tags: rabbitmq, rabbitmq-exchange, dead-letter

I'm getting an strange behavior in my DEV environment. When I send a message to my queue it's dispatched correctly, but the next message (can be same content or different) always fails and is directly sent to my deadletter queue. And then this pattern is repeated, one OK, one sent to deadletter.

In my local setup, everything is working OK, but not in my DEV env so this makes a little difficult to debug/troubleshoot. Not sure what could be wrong or different. I'm new on RabbitMq so maybe I need to include more information (if so please let me know).

Does anyone have an idea of what could be causing it? Or does anyone have experienced something like this before?

RabbitMq Version is: 3.8.2

My rabbitmq.config file is:

```
[{rabbitmq_management,[{tcp_config,[{port,15672}]}]},  {rabbit,[{total_memory_available_override_value,3999997952},           {tcp_listeners,[5672]},           {loopback_users,[]}]}].
```

My two queues are configured this way:

```
**my-queue.dev** 
Type: Classic 
Features: D, DLX

**my-queue.dev.deadletter** 
Type: Classic 
Features: D
```

Kind regards!

Comment: Please, share more details about your problem, such as rabbitmq config file, deployment, queue details and/or consumer details.

Comment: @JoséM This is the **rabbitmq.config** file

`[{rabbitmq_management,[{tcp_config,[{port,15672}]}]},
 {rabbit,[{total_memory_available_override_value,3999997952},
          {tcp_listeners,[5672]},
          {loopback_users,[]}]}].`


My two queues are configured this way:

**my-queue.dev**
Type: Classic
Features: D, DLX

**my-queue.dev.deadletter**
Type: Classic
Features: D

This problem started a week ago, before it was working properly. Nothing seems to be changed to cause this problem.

Comment: Please, edit the question with the new information, that way it's easier to format/read and all the question information is in one place. Regarding your question, I'd say that this is a consumer issue. The consumer may be nack'ing the messages, causing them to be deadlettered (that, or you have some TTL set in the message)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, question updated. 
Regarding the TTL I do not have any TTL when the queue is declared (not using `x-expires` or `x-message-ttl`), same case in the messages (no `Expiration` property used). 

The weird thing as I mentioned, same code works in my local environment but in DEV. 
Having no traffic, if I send 2 times the same message (or can be different one) the first time goes to deadletter then is processed OK, next time it repeats

It tells me that probably there is something different between local and dev but so far, everything looks the same.

Comment: In that case, I'd suggest tracing the consumer code or obtaining a .pcap from the consumer-broker communication (wireshark/tcpdump). Messages are dead-lettered only in three cases: Expiration, queue length limit reached and negative acknowledge. With the tracing/pcap you'll be sure if it's a consumer issue or a broker issue